# Errors in Deploying Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cloud-messaging, node-modules

I had the a `@grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0` error thrown when deploying my cloud functions. I installed `nvm` and updated node to 12.13.1 with firebase tools version 7.8.1. I ran npm install again and redeployed my cloud functions and got the following error message thrown:

> Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase'
>
> Require stack:
>
> - /Users/chriscynn/Desktop/pretzly/pretzly/functions/index.js
> - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js

I understand this means the firebase module in the node_modules folder does not exist, which is true. So I entered the `npm install firebase` command and at the very bottom I've pasted in entirety what prints out.

Any help would be appreciated, been toiling for the past couple days - clearing, installing, reinstalling, uninstalling, etc - and can't find a glimmer of hope in resolving. I'm fairly new to programming and even worse in understanding CLI.

### My current `package.json` is...

[image]

### CLI npm install firebase Error Log

> **1.** grpc@1.20.0 install /Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc
>
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
> https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and
> node@12.13.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile
> with node-gyp)
>
> **2.** *Rows of "CXX(target) Release/obj.target..." print out*
>
> **3.** ../ext/channel.cc:292:56: error: too few arguments to function call,
> expected 2, have 1
> int try_to_connect =
> (int)info[0]->Equals(Nan::True());
>
> /Users/me/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:2616:3:
> note: 'Equals' declared here   V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe
> Equals(Local context,
>
> /Users/me/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8config.h:351:31:
> note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
> define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT attribute((warn_unused_result))
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc_node/ext/channel.o] Error 1
>
> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
>
> gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
>
> gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
>
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown"
> "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0"
> "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>
> Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/me/Desktop/appName/appName/functions/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the firebase and firebase/app modules, considering that they're intended for use in web browsers and not so much for node?  Usually for backends, just firebase-admin is used.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the comment. Not entirely sure if I'm answering correctly, but via the index.js file, I have firebase modules to send push notifications and to also update firestore data.

Answer (score 1):

the problem in that log is that you are installing `grpc` version 1.20.0, which does not support Node 12. You need to either remove whichever library depends on `grpc`, or use a newer version of `grpc`, or use an older version of Node.

Answer (score 0):

The things you're trying to do can all be done with firebase-admin.  Don't use the other Firebase web client libraries, as they're not meant for node.  Just remove all the other firebase dependencies except for firebase-admin and firebase-functions to get started.

Comment: I removed the other firebase dependencies from the package.json file, restarted CLI, deleted the node_modules folder and re-entered the command npm install, followed by redeploying but I am still getting the same error thrown...any thoughts?

Comment: Use the process of elimination.  Keep removing things until it works, then add things back in until you figure out what other module might be causing problems.

Comment: @chris, Did you remove your npm install firebase and replace it with npm install firebase-admin?

Comment: You have to remove `"firebase": "^5.10.0"` from your package.json file.

Comment: So I found out by process of elimination the error is thrown when firebase-admin is installed.. @AtlanteAvila I've removed all firebase related packages excluding firebase-admin and firebase-functions.

Comment: Can you try running `sudo npm install -g node-gyp`?

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version.  Today it's 8.8.0.

Comment: my lord. @AtlanteAvila i believe your suggested command line did it for me..thank you for guiding my escape from purgatory.

Comment: You might want to consider using node via nvm so that you can better control where modules get installed.  It's always easier to stay away from system folders and keep everything in your home directory whenever possible.  Then you will never have to use sudo.  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

First of All You need to make sure to remove any conflicting versions of npm

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

second use the following to install latest of npm

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

that's for Debian distros, for another OS check this link: 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages

Alternatively, you can also use

sudo npm install -g npm@latest

or for version 8.13.0 particularly

```
 sudo npm install -g npm@8.13.0
```